# Cannot import qgis package on python app?

Tags: python, import, package, python-import, qgis

I've a little issue on my python script. I want to import qgis.core to use qgis function in my script but I can't import this package.
I work on python virtual environment with python 3.7 and Qgis work with python 3.7 too.
When I run `import qgis.core`
I obtain this answer :

```
No module named 'qgis'
```

This is normal because I can't install it with conda/pip install. In my conda shell when I run `conda install qgis.core`, I have :

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - qgis.core
```

Any idea to help me please ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, for this kind of package like others (TensorFlow, geopandas, gdal, etc) it's important to create a new python environment to install this special code. I do recommend it. You can create it in Anaconda Navigator. Click on Environments in Anaconda Navigator (see the picture below). In this option, you can choose the python version and the name of your new env. After that, click on Home in Anaconda Navigator (Figura below) and Install the Spyder for your new environment. It can be done in Anaconda Navigator.

[image]

2. Second.

In anaconda prompt activate your_new_env (conda activate your_new_env)

Install qgis ( conda install -c conda-forge qgis)

3. Go to Anaconda Navigator, Choose your_new_env in Home Applications on: then open spyder. Open spyder.
4. Try to import qgis

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I create my new virtuel python environment directly with the prompt of Anaconda. I found the solution, I install qgis with conda forge and it seems to work !